# inequality of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Given that $f$ is continuous, decreasing and always positive on $[0,1]$, show that

$$ \frac{\operatorname{\Large\int}_0^1  \ xf^2(x)dx}{\operatorname{\Large\int}_0^1 xf (x)dx}  \leq \frac{\operatorname{\Large\int}_0^1  f^2(x)dx}{\operatorname{\Large\int}_0^1  f (x)dx}. $$

I am trying to prove this but I do not get any lead, any hint is appreciated

Comment: With the / symbol what do you mean? May be a division?

Comment: yes it is   division

Comment: Please avoid no-clue questions.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
  \int_0^1\int_0^1 & (x-y)f^2(x)f(y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y   =
\int_0^1\int_0^y(x-y)f^2(x)f(y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\ + \\
& \int_0^1\int_0^x(x-y)f^2(x)f(y)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x =
\int_0^1\int_0^y(x-y)\big[f^2(x)f(y)-f(x)f^2(y)\big]\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
<0,
\end{align*}

since $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: how does this prove the statement

Comment: Make a common denominator, you get two integrals from both sides both in dx. Change the variable of integration of one integral in y and due to Fubini's theorem you get a double integral on $[0,1]^2$. Then apply what @edwinFranks has written above.